# VSCode/TextMate syntax highlighting grammar -- matching code until end of line

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, grammar, vscode-extensions, textmate

I am writing a TextMate grammar to implement syntax highlighting in VSCode for a custom flavor of Markdown. I would like everything on the same line after `@@$`  to be highlighted as Javascript.

This is what I came up with:

```json
"majsdown_execute_statement": {
    "begin": "(.*?)(@@\\$)",
    "name": "test",
    "end": "(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)",
    "beginCaptures": {
        "2": {
            "name": "keyword.control.majsdown"
        }
    },
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "source.js"
        }
    ]
},
```

That *almost* works:

[image: what happens]

But I would like the `@@$` part to always be highlighted as a keyword. Here's a mockup (edited image) of my desired result:

[image: what I would like]

I've tried a lot of different combinations of `"begin"` and `"end"`, and I've also tried many nested patterns like the following one:

```json
"patterns": [
    {
        "begin": "\\s",
        "while": "^(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)",
        "patterns": [
            {
                "include": "source.js"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Unfortunately, nothing provides the result I desire. **How can I achieve my desired result?**

Comment: Can you use a positive lookbehind? `(?<=@@\\$)`

Answer (score 0):

To handle multiline constructs, I think you'll have to provide modified embedded language(JavaScript) definition as well. Easiest way to do it would be to make `@@$` a comment in JavaScript, so it'll not mess up existing constructs.

I have no idea about VScode [syntax highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide). I'll try to demonstrate the idea using [HighlightJs](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language-guide.html). It has very similar way of defining a language.
Demo: View in full page mode.

```js
hljs.debugMode();

    // default code for the demo
    src.innerText = `
My custom markdown highlighted with custom rules.
Here is how javascript code looks:
@@$ function test()
@@$ {
@@$   // TODO: stuff
@@$   let rand = Math
@@$                  .random()
@@$                  .toFixed(2);
@@$ }
@@$ var string = "hello";
@@$ const string2 = \`some long
@@$ string\`;

Leave one empty line to get out of the code block.
Here is some more code:
@@$ var rand = Math.random();
@@$ console.log(rand);

We are out of the second code block now.
`;

    // define our markup language, say 'mdown'
    let langDef = {
      name: 'Mdown',
      aliases: ['mdown'],
      case_insensitive: true,
      contains: [
        {
          className: 'mscript',
          begin: /@@/,
          end: /\$/,
          keywords: { name: 'mscript' },
          contains: [],
          starts: {
            end: /^\s*$/, // end on empty line
            returnEnd: true,
            subLanguage: ['js'],  //embedded language
          },
        },
      ],
    };
    hljs.registerLanguage('mscript', () => langDef);

    // patch javascript multiline structures
    let js = hljs.getLanguage('javascript');
    for (let c of js.contains) {
      if (c.begin === "`") {  // handle templet literals
        c.contains.unshift({
          begin: /^@@/, 
          "relevance": 0,
          end: /\$/,
          contains: [],
          scope: 'mscripttag'
        })
      }
    }
    // console.log(js);

    // make '@@$' a comment :)
    // So it'll not mess existing styling
    js.contains.push(hljs.COMMENT(/@@/, /\$/, { scope: 'mscripttag', relevance: 10 }));


    // for demo update highlighted code on user input
    let handleChange = (event) => {
      let html = hljs.highlight(src.innerText, { language: 'mscript', ignoreIllegals: true }).value;
      code.innerHTML = html;
    };
    // javascript patching done

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handleChange);
    src.addEventListener('input', handleChange);
```

```css
body { font-size: .8rem; }

.input {
  width: 46%;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}

.output {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* add extra theme for our tag @@$ */
.hljs { color: #bbb !important; }

.hljs-mscript,
.hljs-mscripttag { color: red; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.4.0/styles/base16/snazzy.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.4.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

<div>Edit below markdown code.</div>
<pre class="input"><div id="src" contenteditable></div></pre>

<pre class="output"><code id="code" class="javascript hljs">abcd</code></pre>
```

In case the library not available, here is how the output looks like:

[image]

In above code I have defined `@@$ <jscontent> \n` as a tag in our markdown language definition. And the content will be processed according to the embedded language JavaScript. 
Next I've modified the default JS language definition and added `@@$` as a comment so it'll be harmless to exiting syntax.
 Now we just need to handle template literals which are multiline. In the literal definition I've added `@@$` as a part of the literal, but with different scope/name/styleOption `msscripttag`.

I hope you'll be able to define similar syntax in TextMate for VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

try using match instead...

```json
"patterns": [
        {
          "name": "keyword.control.factory",
          "match": "(\\w|-)[^(]*"
        }
      ]
```

this code matches everything up to a "(" character

so your code look something like this:

```json
"majsdown_execute_statement": {
    "patterns": [
        {
          "name": "keyword.control.majsdown",
          "match": "(?<=@@\$)\\w*"
        }
      ]
    }
```

you can also try `[^@@$]*(\\w)`

try it out [here](https://regex101.com)

Comment: i updated my answer, made a mistake when pasting....